# Bruteforcing the ceaser cipher

Tags: python, cryptography

I wanted to write an algorithm for bruteforcing shift ciphers based on the Ceaser cipher decryption algorithm that I implemented in Python as below

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def decrypt(cipher: str):
        "Decrypts text encrtyted in Ceaser's cipher"
        plaintext = []
        for i in cipher:
            p = (letters.find(i) - 3) % 26 #Decryption algorithm: p = (c-k) mod 26
                                           #where; c is the index of the letter in the alphabet and k is the key
            if i == "-":
                plaintext.append(" ")
            else:
                if p < 0: #if the number is a negative, ignore mod 26 and instead, directly sum to 26
                    p = p + 26
                else:
                    plaintext.append(letters[p])
        return "".join(plaintext)
```

I tried wrapping the code around a while loop to cycle through the possible combinations but everything just broke.

```
def bruteforce(cipher: str):
    "Cycles through all possible shifts"
    n = 1
    while n <= 26:
        plaintext = []
        for i in cipher.upper():
            p = (letters.find(i) - n) % 26
            if i == "-":
                plaintext.append(" ")
            else:
                if p < 0:
                    p = p + 26
                else:
                    plaintext.append(letters[p])

        n += 1
    return "".join(plaintext)
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: Do you like your implementation of en/decrypt()? There are more straight forward solutions using `str.maketrans()`?  No problem if you do, just want to know how to approach a solution for you.

Comment: "everything just broke" - It would be very helpful you add the error or the undesired behaviour you get.

Comment: perhaps `decrypt()` could be modified to accept a key and they you could call it in a loop from `bruteforce()`.

Comment: It's spelled Caesar and it was originally pronounced more like the German Kaiser, "kai-zar".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is plaintext variable been reseted every time in loop, so plaintext in the end contains only letters with shift n = 26, and previous results are lost

You can put plaintext outside the loop and create inner variable to concat in the end of every iteration

In code I deleted unnecessary condition

Code in python

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def bruteforce(cipher: str):
    "Cycles through all possible shifts"
    N = len(letters)
    plaintext = []
    for n in range(N):
        decrypted = []
        for i in cipher.upper():
            p = (letters.find(i) - n - 1) % N
            decrypted.append(" " if i == " " else letters[p])
        plaintext.append("".join(decrypted))
    return plaintext

print(bruteforce("i love icecream"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, I noticed that underneath `while n <= 26`, you redefine plaintext as an empty list upon every iteration of the loop, making it so your list can't gather anything. Move `plaintext = []` to above `while n <= 26` and give it another go.